# Socket: can't see Message

Tags: python, sockets

I'm a python beginner and I'm trying to write a script with a connection to other Devices. Now I'm trying to build the server, who has to receive messages. But if I receive a message, I can't see it in the Shell

Here the code:

```
import socket
HOST='**.**.**.**'
PORT=****
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
data = data.decode("utf-8")
print("Message: " + data)
```

solution if the text isn't longer than 1024:

```
import socket
HOST='**.**.**.**'
PORT=****
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    data1 = data
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
data1 = data1.decode("utf-8")
print("Message: " + data1)
```

Comment: any error ? does it print something ?

Comment: It only prints: "Message:"

Comment: see that part : `if not data: break` mean that there is no data to print when the loop break

Comment: If I delete it, then it prints nothing

Comment: yes, it cause an infinite loop because you never stop the loop then. What you could do is to print chunk of message when received in the loop, or save them in an other variable

Comment: I have found the answer: I have to make a new Variable called data_1 and put it in the loop: 

        data1 = data

Comment: But then you'll only save the last chunk of the message, if it's longer than 1024 , you'll lost the first parts

Answer (score 0):

Before line `conn.close()`, use `conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD)`. See more details in [socket documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html).

> **Note close()**: releases the resource associated with a connection but
>   does not necessarily close the connection immediately. If you want to
>   close the connection in a timely fashion, call shutdown() before
>   close().